# angularjs losing decimal & negative vals ignored

Tags: angularjs

I've got a short form where the values need to be totaled so I can do math with them. For whatever reason, values set via input-radio turn the numbers into strings, and the only way I can find for angularjs to get numbers to stay numbers is using math.round or math.floor. Both of these convert fractions to whole numbers, so I end up with wacky things like .5, 1, and .5 being equal to 1, instead of two. Even if I finagle things to do whole numbers, I'm also trying to do negative numbers, and those just seem to be skipped.

Here's the specific part that's giving me fits. I've got the vars spelled out so I can output them in the html, but the final version would use the line that's commented out.

```
$scope.updateValue = function () {
  var one = $window.Math.floor($scope.one);
  var two = $window.Math.floor($scope.two);
  var three = $window.Math.floor($scope.three);      
  $scope.perperson = (one + two + three); 
//$scope.perperson =  $window.Math.floor($scope.one + $scope.two + $scope.three);  
  $scope.population = $window.Math.floor($scope.perperson * $scope.total);
```

};

[Here's the plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/5yDhfchKmzICfitylckg?p=preview) How can I get the numbers to stay as fractions, and to subtract negative numbers instead of ignore them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an Angular issue so much as it's a JavaScript issue.

To convert a string to a number in JavaScript you can use:

```
parseFloat('1.4'); //1.4
parseInt('1.4'); //1
+'1.4'; //1.4  (+ works like shorthand for parseFloat)
```

Outside of that, as far as Angular is concerned, whatever you put in `value="1234"` is a string. .. because it's a string. ;)

Here's an updated plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/XRcAqML0jYm5IqIiaXSX?p=preview

Comment: ahah, shortcuts are the awesome. thank you! I'd tried using parseInt but I have no idea what I was doing (or not) that it didn't work. More to the point, if I use parseInt or parseFloat instead, does that mean I don't actually need the $window.Math.round bit?

Comment: Yes, you don't need Math.round. That will just convert the string to a number, then it will round the number. All numbers in JavaScript are 64 bit floats, complete with rounding errors. If you want to have some fun, try `.1 + .2` sometime. ;)